# MongoDB insert field to existing document if does not already exist

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a document like this (this is very simplified):

```
{
    'name' : 'test',
    'age' : 16
}
```

and also this

```
{
    'name' : 'test2'
}
```

I want to set all 'age' to 14 if it does not exist.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `$exists` [operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists):

```
$this->mongolib->update('people', array('age' => array('$exists' => false)), array('$set' => array('age' => 14)), array('upsert' => true, 'multiple' => true));
```

Comment: Wouldn't you accomplish the same if you where searching for an null value for age ?

Comment: `$exists` won't match `{age: null}`, but searching where age is null would match docs with no age field. I find the $exists operator to be a better indicator of intent.

Comment: Will not this just create a new document?

Answer (score 0):

I have a roundabout way that I can think of. I suggest you use the normal update command but just add a regex condition in your selection criteria to match only those documents that do not have a value (or numeric value) set for the 'age' attribute.